# Lombok inheritance with @EqualsAndHashCode

Tags: java, java-8, lombok

I have a class which extends a parent class using @EqualsAndHashCode.  I am getting a compilation error with Lombok 1.16.0 and Java 8

`@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true, of = { "propertyA", "propertyB" })
public class Parent {...}`

`@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, doNotUseGetters = true, of = { "propertyC", "propertyD" })
public class Child extends Parent {...}`

The error is...

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project granger: Compilation failure`
`[ERROR] /Users/sarah/src/main/java/com/xxx/Child.java:[26,1] canEqual(java.lang.Object) in com.xxx.Child cannot override canEqual(java.lang.Object) in com.yyy.Parent`
`[ERROR] attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public`

Is there any best practice around inheritance and @EqualsAndHashCode and Lombok that I am abusing?  Or any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the classes are in different artifacts or you made an incremental build.

Before 1.14 `canEqual`was `public`, since then it's `protected`.

If you make a `clean` and / or compile `Parent` using Lombok 1.16 it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you made this build you would end up with a broken `equals` method, because it won't be symmetric (`parent.equals(child)` if they have the same values in the parent fields, but never `child.equals(parent)`). It's been a while since I used Lombok, but scala case classes (which are more or less equivalent in this regard) cannot extend other case classes for this reason.

Think very carefully about what `Parent` and `Child` represent. Is `Child` really Liskov-substitutable for `Parent`? If so, it might be better to inherit the definition of `equals` and `hashCode` from `Parent`, and not try to redefine them in `Child` at all; if not, it might be better to extract the common functionality into a common superclass which both `Parent` and `Child` extend, rather than having them as parent and child.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply.  I think this explains the best course of action, but zeroflag's answer explains why this was technically occurring.

Comment: Actually, Lombok does it right, see [this comment](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1669#issuecomment-383201377). It support both cases, but you may need to override `canEqual` to get it right. There are cases when allowing instances of subclasses to be equal is essential, e.g., Hibernate proxies.